# Checking for null when calling a function in JavaScript shortcut?

Tags: javascript

Is there a shorter way to check for null when calling a function in JavaScript? (besides removing the curly braces).  I always do the following for safety.

```
if (errorNotificationFn) {
  errorNotificationFn(errorString);
}
```

I like the `??` operator and was wondering if there is something similar for function calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use [*optional chaining*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) which was brought in at the same time the nullish coalescing operator you mentioned was:

```
errorNotificationFn?.(errorString);
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^
```

It's not just for function calls, it also short-circuits property evalution, for instance:

```
example = this?.that?.theOther?.();
```

will either A) set `example` to `undefined` if `this`, `that`, or `theOther` is either `null` or `undefined`, or B) set `example` to the result of calling `this.that.theOther()`.

Works with brackets, too:

```
value = object["example"]?.something;
```

In that, if `object["example"]` is `null` or `undefined`, `value` receives `undefined`; otherwise, it receives the value from `object["example"].something`.